# Match value then return value of cell to left or right

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a range of cells that have different values. I would like to match values of cell but return the values of cell either to the left or right. For simplicity, let's just say I want the cell 1 column to the left:

[image]

Would appreciate any pointers

Comment: What about c3, would that not return also?

Comment: do you want both, or one?

Comment: Hi there Scott, if you show me how to return 1 column to the left, I can probably figure out from the formula how to do the rest.

Comment: As ComradeMicha mentioned, your table format doesn't make it easy to process without VBA.  Could you reformat the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the following:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$F$8,INT(AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$3:$F$8)+(COLUMN($A$3:$F$8)/1000))/($A$3:$F$8=$B$10),ROW(1:1))),INT(AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN($A$3:$F$8)+(ROW($A$3:$F$8)/1000))/(((ROW($A$3:$F$8)+(COLUMN($A$3:$F$8)/1000))=AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$3:$F$8)+(COLUMN($A$3:$F$8)/1000))/($A$3:$F$8=$B$10),ROW(1:1)))*($A$3:$F$8=$B$10)),1)-1))
```

[image]

Comment: @Dergyll, but do you actually understand it?

Comment: @Dergyll See edit, fixed the formula to allow for duplicates in a row.

Comment: my original sheet was a little more messy, but I used something like this:

Answer (score -2):

Since VLookup only works if your key is the leftmost item in the range and even then only if the range is a flat table from top to bottom, I think you can only do this using VBA. If your data is always exactly that format, you could also simply hardcode one row at the bottom with a specific cell at the top, if it matches the lookup value write the data, then filter the rows to remove errors/empty cells.

In VBA you just specify the starting point of your lookup data, loop through the cells (either down or to the right, then wrap around when you reach emptyness until you're not finding any more data), compare the cell value to your lookup calue and if it matches, write the data entry at the bottom.

Comment: this is more comment than answer.  If you wanted to show how this would be done with the existing data setup in vba, then it would be an answer.